# Another way to Optimize the results of a SQL VB.NET

Tags: sql, windows, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am experiencing some slowness problems is trying to refresh my datagrid with this code, 
What I'm trying to do is manipulate the columns ACROSS variable (selltype_code).

```
objConn.Open()

            Dim sqlConn As String = ("SELECT item_code, item_name, item_quantity, selltype_code, item_selldetail FROM qa_items")
            Dim objDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn, objConn)
            Dim ds As New DataSet

            objDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "items")

            'Fill datagridview with FOR CICLE
            For i As Int16 = 0 To ds.Tables("items").Rows.Count - 1
                If ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("selltype_code") = 1 Then
                    With Me.resultitems_seach_item
                        .Item(3, i).Style.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(39, 74, 109)) 'Color para Precio
                        .Item(3, i).Value = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("item_selldetail") 'Valor para Precio
                        .Item(4, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(4, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(5, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(5, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(6, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(6, i).Value = "---"
                    End With
                ElseIf ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("selltype_code") = 2 Then
                    With Me.resultitems_seach_item
                        .Item(3, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(3, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(4, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(4, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(5, i).Style.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(39, 74, 109)) 'Color para Precio
                        .Item(5, i).Value = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("item_selldetail")
                        .Item(6, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(6, i).Value = "---"
                    End With
                ElseIf ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("selltype_code") = 3 Then
                    With Me.resultitems_seach_item
                        .Item(3, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(3, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(4, i).Style.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(39, 74, 109)) 'Color para Precio
                        .Item(4, i).Value = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("item_selldetail")
                        .Item(5, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(5, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(6, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(6, i).Value = "---"
                    End With
                Else
                    With Me.resultitems_seach_item
                        .Item(3, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(3, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(4, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(4, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(5, i).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                        .Item(5, i).Value = "---"
                        .Item(6, i).Style.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(39, 74, 109)) 'Color para Precio
                        .Item(6, i).Value = ds.Tables("items").Rows(i).Item("item_selldetail")
                    End With
                End If

            Next i

            objConn.Close()
```

Comment: Don't select _all_ the items in the table. The larger it grows, the slower your code would seem. Introduce paging.

Comment: why not using a background worker component to execute the lengthy work to avoid the ui sluggish behavior

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you turn off any autoresize settings for grid columns. That slows down fetches considerably. Set the Grid AutoresizeMode to NONE before doing the refresh.